# Modify custom block plugin without losing content

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor

I'm developing a custom block plugin with the standard environment built with:

```
npx @wordpress/create-block my-plugin-name
```

I have now inserted some content using this block. Works fine. Good!

After a while, I want to make a modification to the block to fine-tune its design. After running the script to compile it (`yarn build` or `yarn start`), the content I had previously entered is lost. In the editor a message appears saying that the block has an unexpected error and offers me the possibility of trying to recover the block, but the attempt always fails.

I have to insert the content again in a new block.

[image]

So, after insert content I cant't make a plugin modificaton without losing my content.

How can I develop a plugin preserving the content?

[This is the plugin in GitHub](https://github.com/aitormendez/giraldez-blocks/tree/main/blocks/muestradatos)

**block.json**

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/block.json",
    "apiVersion": 2,
    "name": "giraldez-block/muestradatos",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "title": "Muestra datos",
    "category": "giraldez",
    "icon": "megaphone",
    "description": "Muestra tres datos en grande con el diseño inclinado de AG.",
    "supports": {
        "align": [ "wide", "full" ],
        "html": false
    },
    "textdomain": "giraldez-blocks",
    "editorScript": "file:./index.js",
    "editorStyle": "file:./index.css",
    "style": "file:./style-index.css",
        "attributes": {
        "leyenda1": {
            "type": "string",
            "default": ""
        },
        "dato1": {
            "type": "string",
            "default": ""
        },
        "leyenda2": {
            "type": "string",
            "default": ""
        },
        "dato2": {
            "type": "string",
            "default": ""
        },
        "leyenda3": {
            "type": "string",
            "default": ""
        },
        "dato3": {
            "type": "string",
            "default": ""
        }
    }
}
```

**edit function**

```
export default function Edit( { attributes, setAttributes } ) {
    
    return (
        <div { ...useBlockProps() }>
            <div>
                <TextControl
                    label={ __( 'Leyenda 1', 'giraldez-blocks' ) }
                    value={ attributes.leyenda1 }
                    onChange={ ( val ) => setAttributes( { leyenda1: val } ) }
                />
                <TextControl
                    label={ __( 'Dato 1', 'giraldez-blocks' ) }
                    value={ attributes.dato1 }
                    onChange={ ( val ) => setAttributes( { dato1: val } ) }
                />
            </div>

            <div>
                <TextControl
                    label={ __( 'Leyenda 2', 'giraldez-blocks' ) }
                    value={ attributes.leyenda2 }
                    onChange={ ( val ) => setAttributes( { leyenda2: val } ) }
                />
                <TextControl
                    label={ __( 'Dato 2', 'giraldez-blocks' ) }
                    value={ attributes.dato2 }
                    onChange={ ( val ) => setAttributes( { dato2: val } ) }
                />
            </div>

            <div>
                <TextControl
                    label={ __( 'Leyenda 3', 'giraldez-blocks' ) }
                    value={ attributes.leyenda3 }
                    onChange={ ( val ) => setAttributes( { leyenda3: val } ) }
                />
                <TextControl
                    label={ __( 'Dato 3', 'giraldez-blocks' ) }
                    value={ attributes.dato3 }
                    onChange={ ( val ) => setAttributes( { dato3: val } ) }
                />
            </div>

        </div>
    );
}
```

**save function**

```
 export default function save( { attributes } ) {
    const blockProps = useBlockProps.save();
    return <div { ...blockProps }>
        <div className={`flex justify-between -skew-x-12 not-prose ${attributes.align}`.trimEnd()}>
            <div className='flex flex-col p-4 border-l-4 border-r-4 blqe border-rojo border-b-20 bg-blanco'>
                <p className='my-4 mt-0 text-2xl font-bold skew-x-12 leyenda text-rojo'>{ attributes.leyenda1 }</p>
                <p className='my-0 text-5xl font-bold skew-x-12 dato text-rojo'>{ attributes.dato1 }</p>
            </div>
            <div className='flex flex-col p-6 border-r-4 blqe border-rojo border-b-20 bg-blanco'>
                <p className='my-4 mt-0 text-2xl font-bold skew-x-12 leyenda text-rojo'>{ attributes.leyenda2 }</p>
                <p className='my-0 text-5xl font-bold skew-x-12 dato text-rojo'>{ attributes.dato2 }</p>
            </div>
            <div className='flex flex-col p-6 border-r-4 blqe border-rojo border-b-20 bg-blanco'>
                <p className='my-4 mt-0 text-2xl font-bold skew-x-12 leyenda text-rojo'>{ attributes.leyenda3 }</p>
                <p className='my-0 text-5xl font-bold skew-x-12 dato text-rojo'>{ attributes.dato3 }</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>;
}
```

Comment: note that the content is not blocked, it just doesn't match the GUI, if you go to the frontend and look in the database that content is still there. I see you did not share code, can you edit your question to include code? It's very very difficult to answer this question without code, if it's possible at all.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've linked a GitHub repo with the entire plugin (I'm not sure what part of the code you need exactly). Question updated.

Comment: ideally all of it, at an absolute minimum the javascript, and it should be in your question rather than a link, otherwise this question becomes useless once you take the github repo down. Also it's not clear what you changed as there's only 1 commit and no git history. Additionally, are you sure you want to store your attributes in the HTML that gets saved using selectors?

Comment: I'm not sure. What is the good practice here? I'm learning, but is hard. I have no much level. I added the JS to the question. Also, tried to remove source from attrs in order to store data in comment delimiter. Problem persists. Every time I do a "npm run build" the blocks inserted becomes broken.

Comment: UPDATE: Now, using comment delimiter to store data the recover button works! So this is the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To prevent this kind of error whenever you change the block structure, I suggest using Dynamic Block instead. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/creating-dynamic-blocks/).